# Firefox Form Submit Disconnects Socket

Tags: forms, sockets, firefox, flask

I'm creating a basic form in Javascript to submit an image to a Flask-powered server.

```
form  = document.createElement('FORM');
form.method = 'POST';
form.enctype = 'multipart/form-data';
```

...

```
var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
input.setAttribute('type','file');
input.setAttribute('accept','.jpg, .jpeg, .png');
input.addEventListener('change', handleFiles, false);
input.name = 'file';
```

Then I have a button that upon click submits the form:

```
function fileSubmitClick() {
    form.submit();
}
```

The issue is that strange things happen on Firefox when the form is submitted: (1) socket communication is disconnected; (2) the Javascript console is cleared. Neither of these happen on Chrome or Safari.

For reference, here's how I'm handling form submission on Flask:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        print('No file part')
        return ('',204)
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        print('No selected file')
        return ('',204)
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    return ('',204)
```

Comment: Why are you returning HTTP 204 on errors? Seems like it should be a  http 400.

Comment: Also is the image actually uploaded on firefox?

Comment: I want Flask to stay on the same page after file submission and I read online that ('',204) is 'empty response', which achieves that (and indeed it does).

Comment: And yes, I'm able to load an image from Firefox. It's just the upload part (form submit) that behaves weirdly.

Comment: Yeah. I got that. I mean if the browser sends an invalid form do you really want to treat it as a successful upload?

More generally:
1. Closing the socket doesn't seem like an error. If you send keep alive it might keep the connection open though.
2. Clearing the console seems like a firefox bug. Probably worth reporting to the devs but not something that should effect user experience.